# Difficulty with running gradient descent in eager execution

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent, eager-execution

I've built a neural network with python in TensorFlow, but I can't seem to resolve this issue with TensorFlow's eager execution. All the gradients output zero, and I'm not really sure where I've gone wrong in the program.

Originally I was using ReLU, and I thought that was the issue in the network, so I changed it to leaky ReLU. But haven't seen any change in the gradients.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# emabling eager execution
tf.enable_eager_execution()

# establising learning rate
LEARNING_RATE = 20
TRAINING_ITERATIONS = 30
LABELS = tf.constant([0.5, 0.7, 1.0])
# print(LABELS)

# input test vector
init = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))
# print(init)

# declare and intialize all weights
weight1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 3]))
bias1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))
weight2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 2]))
bias2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))
weight3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 3]))
bias3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))
weight4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 2]))
bias4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))
weight5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3]))
bias5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))

VARIABLES = [weight1, bias1, weight2, bias2, weight3, bias3, weight4, bias4, weight5, bias5]
# print(weight1)


def neuralNet(input, y_input):  # nn model aka: Thanouse's Eyes
    layerResult = tf.nn.leaky_relu((tf.matmul(weight1, input) + bias1), alpha=0.1)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.leaky_relu((tf.matmul(weight2, input) + bias2), alpha=0.1)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.leaky_relu((tf.matmul(weight3, input) + bias3), alpha=0.1)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.leaky_relu((tf.matmul(weight4, input) + bias4), alpha=0.1)
    input = layerResult
    layerResult = tf.nn.leaky_relu((tf.matmul(weight5, input) + bias5), alpha=0.1)
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.reshape(layerResult, [-1]))
    return prediction


# print(neuralNet(init, LABELS))
# Begin training and update variables
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

for i in range(TRAINING_ITERATIONS):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:  # gradient calculation
        tape.watch(VARIABLES)
        COST = tf.reduce_sum(LABELS - neuralNet(init, LABELS))
    print(COST)
    GRADIENTS = tape.gradient(COST, VARIABLES)
    # print(GRADIENTS)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(GRADIENTS, VARIABLES))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `persistent` GradientTape. Just remove the argument.

The actual issue is that derivative of `sum(softmax)` is simply always zero because, by definition, the sum of softmax outputs is always 1. So, whatever you do with your variables, you will not be able to reduce the COST you defined.

Comment: But before I calculate the sum, I subtract the softmax vector from LABLES which would change the sum from 1 no?

Comment: LABELS is constant (i.e. changing variables does not change LABELS) so, the COST is not exactly 1 but it is still constant.